# Angular2 http.get start and stop

Tags: jquery, angular

With Jquery ajax, I can do

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() { 
                $("body").addClass("loading");    
                }).ajaxStop(function() { 
                    $("body").removeClass("loading"); 
                });
```

with Angular2 http.get(), is there a way that I can detect the start and stop of the request?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS has a very useful feature: HTTP Interceptors, these ones are services that get automatically called on each ajax request step (before an ajax call, after an ajax call and so on) once they are registered using the $httpProvider.

Simply in your http.get method you can use the following code:

```
$("body").addClass("loading");
$http.get(url).then(function(value) {
        $scope.example1 = value.status; 
        $("body").removeClass("loading"); 
    });
```

But if you want it will work globally I mean every http(GET/POST) call it will show the loading and after the success/error hide the loading.

You can read this articles:

http://www.daveoncode.com/2015/04/29/angularjs-centralized-application-loading-status-handling-using-http-interceptors/

http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2013/01/02/using-response-interceptors-to-show-and-hide-a-loading-widget/

I think it will serve your wants.

Comment: thanks, with ng2, we have to extend the Http class.  I will look into that.  thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

**Angular2 http returns Observables** which makes everything very simple.

Observable has **finally** method, you can put the **remove code** inside that.

below code is a simple implementation.

```
document.querySelector('body').classList.add('loading');
this._http.get(url)
  .finally(() => {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('loading');
  })
  .subscribe(
    res => { console.log('success result --', res); },
    err => { console.log('error', err); },
    () => { console.log('completed'); }
  )
```

if you want to implement it commonly for all http get call.

Just create `CustomHttp` like below, and use `CustomHttp` instead of `http`, anywhere in your appliaction.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
  }

  get(url: string, options?) {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('loading');
    return this._http.get(url, options).finally(() => {
      document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('loading');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: very interesting thought.  Will definitely try this.